# Additional assumptions for the robust optimization paradigm

Tags: optimization

**Please, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02634.pdf) at page 3**: could you help to understand the proofs from E.1 to E.4? In particular:

- why, by adding the constraint $\operatorname{c^Tx}-t\leq 0$, did the objective function become certain?
- What's the meaning of *uncertain right-side side of a constraint*? I don't understand the rule of $x_{n+1}=-1$.

Then, for E.3 and E.4, total darkness.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

E.1 is the usual linearization of a min-max problem, replacing the max with an explicit variable $t$ and imposing a constraint on $t$.  The uncertainty of $c$ has now moved from the objective to a constraint.

For E.2, suppose you have some constraint $\sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j} x_j \le d_i$, where $d_i$ is uncertain.  You can introduce a new variable $x_{n+1}$ and rewrite the constraint as two constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j} x_j + d_i x_{n+1} &\le 0 \\
x_{n+1} &= -1
\end{align}
The uncertainty of $d_i$ has now moved from the right-hand side to the left-hand side (a constraint coefficient).

Comment: Really thanks for your answer! Now the first two points are clear. Instead, what can you tell me about E.3 and E.4?